# How to set MapView Zoom Level in onCreate() ? 

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview

I'm developing a OneMap Android application and the code is as follows:

```
    private MapView map;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map); 

        map.addLayer(new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(Practice_3.this,
                "http://www.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/BASEMAP/MapServer"));}
```

I'm lost at figuring out **how to set the zoom level when the map is first loaded** on the emulator as on load, the map is too small.

Could anyone help me with this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many tutorials available online for Google Maps applications with Android. It seem to be you didn't check them. Don't use stackoverflow for basic things, its not good.

Comment: @Yugandhar Babu you're right, but these words here don't looks friendly

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyMap_MapControllerActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    //private MapController mapController;
     MapView.LayoutParams lp;
     int y = 10;
        int x = 10;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapView.setTraffic(true);



    GeoPoint center = mapView.getMapCenter();
    int latSpan = mapView.getLatitudeSpan();
    int longSpan = mapView.getLongitudeSpan();




    lp = new MapView.LayoutParams(MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    x, y,
    MapView.LayoutParams.TOP_LEFT);
    View zoomControls = mapView.getZoomControls();
    mapView.addView(zoomControls, lp);
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
    }



    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to know your current location, now you can use new location api, here is the [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).
then you can add below command under `Onconnect()`

```
LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());         
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(2.0f));
```

but remember .connect() [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) under onCreate().

here is the error message you will get if you not follow 
[Android: at com.google.android.gms.internal.u.y(Unknown Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827097/android-at-com-google-android-gms-internal-u-yunknown-source)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you`re using ArcGIS maps. 
Please use the below sample code to set zoom level on the launch of the maps.

```
<com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    mapoptions.MapType="Topo"
    mapoptions.ZoomLevel="13"
    mapoptions.center="33.666354, -117.903557" />
```

you can also set in activity file,

```
 MapOptions options = new MapOptions(MapType.TOPO, 23, -110, 9);
```

Let me know if it works for you.