# Android: at com.google.android.gms.internal.u.y(Unknown Source)

Tags: android, location, location-client

I try to get current location, following the guide from http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

my google play service is up, however my locationclient still can't connected, and getting those error when i running the program.
(PS: previously my location code is working, but now can't, strange)

here you go

```
package com.example.Wifin;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class myMap extends Activity implements
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {

     GoogleMap mMap;
     LatLng Current;
     Marker here;
     LocationClient mLocationClient;
     int resultCode;
     Location mCurrentLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        resultCode =GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode){
            Log.d("Location Updates",
                    "Google Play services is available.");

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Service Error " + resultCode,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

        mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

        Current = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        here = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(Current)
                                .title("you're here!")
                                .snippet("Connect to home2, Signal Strenght -20dBm")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.testmarker)));

    }





    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {

    }


}
```

below is my catlog

```
09-16 21:31:37.187: D/dalvikvm(14050): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 259K, 5% free 8612K/8992K, paused 14ms, total 15ms
09-16 21:31:37.447: D/dalvikvm(14050): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 816K, 10% free 8307K/9176K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
09-16 21:31:37.527: D/dalvikvm(14050): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 301K, 8% free 8517K/9176K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
09-16 21:31:37.607: D/dalvikvm(14050): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 311K, 5% free 8717K/9176K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
09-16 21:31:37.627: D/Location Updates(14050): Google Play services is available.
09-16 21:31:37.637: D/AndroidRuntime(14050): Shutting down VM
09-16 21:31:37.637: W/dalvikvm(14050): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4180f700)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Wifin/com.example.Wifin.myMap}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.u.y(Unknown Source)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.cm.a(Unknown Source)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.cm$c.y(Unknown Source)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.cl.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.cm.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at com.example.Wifin.myMap.onCreate(myMap.java:51)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-16 21:31:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(14050):    ... 11 more
09-16 21:31:37.927: D/dalvikvm(14050): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 300K, 4% free 8930K/9284K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
09-16 21:31:38.987: I/Process(14050): Sending signal. PID: 14050 SIG: 9

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.Wifin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>

    <permission android:name="com.example.Wifin.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>   
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.Wifin.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

here is my manifest file

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle" > 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>          
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">           
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".myMap" 
                  android:label="@string/myMap"
            />

        <receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
         </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


     <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="AIzaSyDlimK4K3HlYCjYHP4k9k6c-DWC0z-8JQ8"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check are you added the googleplay services library to your project

Comment: i added...and i go to add again

Comment: what you have in line 51..

Comment: @Aravinth that empty line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look here

```
Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
```

You should call `.connect()` .. then do the method in `onConnected()`.

Because if it's not connected, and you are trying to access the internet it'll crash.

Comment: i put .connect() to onConnected(), still same problem, and i think it should be under onStart(), because connect when this activity start.sa

Comment: no! first you should connect to the socket .. then if the connection is true the method in onConnect will be made

Comment: what you mean connect to the socket? but anyway, even add connect() to Onconnected() listener, it still same problem

Comment: the **        mLocationClient.connect();
** should be under the setconectview in oncreate

Comment: same problem happened :(

Comment: Problem solved by put the method under Onconnected(), and .connect at Oncreate(), thanks

Answer (score 0):

The thing that seems wrong to me is `mLocationClient.connect();` inside `onConnected()` method because `onConnected()` is a method of `GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks` interface which calls `onConnected()` when LocationClient gets conntected to google services and this happens after the call to `mLocationclient.connect()` method. You should use `mLocationClient.connect()` method somewhere else like `onResume()` or `onStart()`.